# ZAP Authentication using API calls

Tags: authentication, owasp, zap

I am using ZAP API calls to test a site using command line. But I have a problem with the user authentication even though I am following the correct steps. But I still can't manage to pass the login page when spider as a user. Below are the steps that I am follwing.

1.Include in the context (context/includeContext)

2.Change Authentication Method to formBased. (authentication/setAutenticationMethod)
    Here I only pass contextID,authMethodName and in authMethodConfigParams only the logiunUrl. Not the loginrequestData. I tried to pass authMethodConfigParams as

`loginUrl=**********************&loginRequestData=username={%username%}&password={%password%}`

but the field doen't fills up when I use this.

3.Set the login Indicator (authentication/setLoggedInIndicator)

4.Enable auto Reauthentication (auth/autoReauthON)

5.Add a new user (users/nweUser)

6.Set credentials for user ( users/setAuthenticationCredentials)

7.Enable user (users/setUserEnabled)

8.Spider as the new user (spider/scanAsUser)

But in spidering it cannot get pass the log in page. When I Open the UI application all the API calls have been worked and all the settings 
have been configured on the session properties. But when I check the POST request it is as below.

```
username=ZAP&password=ZAP&rememberMe=true
```

I think this is the problem. Why doesn't it take the new users credentials??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post your solution here as an answer so others can learn from your problem?

Comment: Sure I will post my solution

Comment: Hey, could you please post you full api here. i have some confusion and i don't know how i post data with api. Thanks in advanced

Comment: Here I have roughly pointed out the api calls needed. Hope it helps. :) https://janitha000.wordpress.com/2015/09/12/owasp-zap-authentication-and-command-line-tool/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in my question was that the way I use to pass authMethodConfigParams was wrong. authMethodConfigParams are expected to be "x-www-form-urlencoded" , not in the normal form. So I used http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ to convert my authMethodConfigParams and passed it on the API. Also when passing scanAsUser I have to pass in "x-www-form-urlencoded" format.
So this was my solution

Answer (score 3):

I use this command and its working//

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://example.com/ -g gen.conf -r testreport.html authMethodName : formBasedAuthentication authMethodConfigParams :loginUrl=http://example.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/&csrfmiddlewaretoken=VA3M5L1y6ieXjb1e9AqRzBdqbgY4afrL&username=admin@admin.com&password=admin&next=/admin/
```